# Converting labels to indicator matrix after dividing the dataset to training and testing

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, neural-network

Converting Y to indicator matrix works fine:

```
file = 'dataset.csv'    
X, Y = readFile(file)
N = len(Y)
T = np.zeros((N, K)) 
for i in range(N):
    T[i, Y[i]] = 1
```

but when I do the same thing after dividing into training and testing, like this: I get error

```
X, Y = shuffle(X, Y)
Ntrain = int(0.7*len(X))
Xtrain, Ytrain = X[:Ntrain], Y[:Ntrain]
Xtest, Ytest = X[Ntrain:], Y[Ntrain:]
N1 = len(Ytrain)
T1 = np.zeros((N1, K))  
for i in range(N1):
    T1[i, Ytrain[i]] = 1
```

It shows error on last line: T1[i, Ytrain[i]] = 1 , Where I am going wrong?
K is the number of classes = 9

```
print(np.unique(Y))
print(np.unique(Ytrain))
```

The above print statements give :

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

[image]

Comment: What is `NTrain`?

Comment: Ntrain = int(0.7*len(X))

Comment: I know. What to know what number `int(0.7*len(X))` yields

Comment: Ntrain is equal to 774. Shape of Xtrain is (774, 12) and Ytrain (774, )

Comment: print `YTrain` and edit your question with the output

Comment: what is the value of K?

Comment: @GerardoFlores K is equal to 9, the total number of classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got solved:
Somehow there was no index with the Ytrain. So I converted the Ytrain to pandas series:

```
data = np.array(Ytrain)
Ytrain1 = pd.Series(data)
N1 = len(Ytrain1)
T1 = np.zeros((N1, K))
for i in range(N1): 
   print(i, Ytrain1[i]) # Prints fine 
   T1[i, Ytrain1[i]] = 1
```

Comment: that's odd. Ytrain has an index since it has shape (774,). Be careful and glad it is working for you now!

Answer (score 1):

T1 is of size N1 * K and you're trying to set the value at index Ytrain[i]. if Ytrain[i] >=  K then you're going to get a KeyError

UPDATE:

```
for i in range(N1):
    print(i)
    T1[i, Ytrain[i]] = 1
```

Comment: The unique values in both Y and Ytrain is [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
Then why is this error only in case of Ytrain and not Y, do you have any idea?

Comment: what's the value of k? also, to help debug and find the exact issue you could check the update on my answer